# Exception when exiting

Tags: chef-recipe

I'm writing a chef recipe as shown below. I hope the recipe can stop to continue executing the resources after this, but without giving the exception.

Do you have any ideas about this except from doing **exit(0)**?

```rb
ruby_block "verify #{current_container_name}" do
  block do
    require "docker"

    begin
      container = Docker::Container.get(current_container_name)
    rescue Docker::Error::NotFoundError => exception
      container = nil
    end

    if container.nil?
      exit(0)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ignore_failure true` in this ruby block instead of handling the exception.  That way it would still output the error messages, but wouldn't treat it as a failure so would continue to execute subsequent resources.

Comment: I hope the chef-client just stops in this resource(not exception) and not continue to execute subsequent resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort a chef-run under a special circumstance - like the current Docker-container is not available - this is not possible. The solution is to rethink your problem - you want some code to be only run when a special condition is met.

You do this by either leaving the recipe (with a `return true`), encapsulating your configuration steps in a conditional-clause (like a `if my_container.nil? then ... end`) or you use node-attributes to step through conditions.

Let's say your cookbook x relies on three recipes, 1, 2 and 3. So if you'd like to define that 2 and 3 are only run if 1 was successful, you're able to to write the state of the 1st recipe into the node-attributes (f.e. `node.normal['recipe1'] = 'successful'`).

In the other recipes you'll then define an entry-gate like:

```rb
return true if node['recipe1'] != 'succesful'
```

But be aware, if you're using node-attributes you'll need to use the `ruby_block`-resource (mostly) at the end of your first recipe because the bare-ruby-code is evaluated and run during the resource-compilation - which takes place before the converge-run.

Comment: Not only leave the ruby block, but also exit the chef-client execution without error.